# How to make div automatically take height of inside content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, vue-component, vuejs3

I have these buttons in a chatbot whose text automatically changes based on any option selected. Sometimes the text is longer and then it doesn't fit for one button.

I wanted to know how to make the current div automatically takes the height of inside content such that it keeps other options in proper grid/alignment too ( 3x3).

I tried using height: auto but that will disorganize the appearance. Used flex but didn't seem to work.

My vue file where these menu buttons are used:

```
<div class="row">
          <template 
            v-for="(item, index) in this.items.slice(0, maxNumberOfItems)" 
            :key="index"
          >
          <div :class="((index >= (this.items.length - 1)) && (index % 2 == 0)) ? 'px-2 pb-2 col': 'px-2 pb-2 col col-6'">
            <Button 
              @on-click="onButtonClick(item)"
              :text="item"
            />
</div>
          </template>
        </div>
```

Comment: So for clarification, in the screenshot above, you would like the "Recreation Activities" button to be slightly taller, since it has 2 lines of text?  And then I assume you would like the "Resident Services" button to also become taller to match it?  If not, could you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to do - is the screenshot included the desired state, or the problem state?  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "disorganize the appearance"?

Comment: You understood it correctly. I want the reaction activities button taller and then the same height should be adjusted to rest of the buttons too. The screenshot included is problem state. The appearance gets disorganized when I used height: auto because the rows didn't appear in grid like structure anymore.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, or solve it yourself https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Change `height` to `min-height` in the button CSS, or remove `height` altogether, since a div would otherwise fit its content automatically.

If you want to maintain vertical space around the text you could use `padding` (or other rules) instead of an explicit height.